# php array list foreach print

Tags: php, arraylist

Hello I have a list as I mentioned below. I want to print foreach and category url separate category_name, but I get such an error. how can i solve it?

```
<a href="CATEGORY_URL">CATEGORY_NAME</a>
```

```
<?php $data = array(
    "category_url" => explode(',', $row['category_url']),
    "category_name" => explode(',', $row['category_name']));
?>

<?php foreach ($data as $value): ?>
    <?php echo $value ?>
<a href="CATEGORY_URL">CATEGORY_NAME</a>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

```
Array
(
    [category_url] => Array
        (
            [0] => css
            [1] => html
        )

    [category_name] => Array
        (
            [0] => css
            [1] => html
        )
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you want to do it this way.

```
<?php $category_url = explode(',', $row['category_url']);
foreach (explode(',', $row['category_name']) as $index => $category_name):?>
    <a href="<?= site_url(trim($category_url[$index])) ?>"><?= $category_name ?></a>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

now that you edited the question, I understood what you mean, `foreach` does not suitable here, you should use `for`:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($data['category_url']); $i++):
   echo "<a href='" . $data['category_url'][$i] . "'>" . $data['category_name'][$i] . "</a>";
endfor;
```

Comment: I only have a situation like this, I want to print category url and separate category name. prints all you say as $ value

Comment: so why you just don't use print_r($value)?

Comment: I didn't quite understand what you mean.. print_r($value)
```css html css html```

Comment: in your code use print_r instead of echo to print category_url array and category_name array

Comment: are you really kidding? Would you try it yourself at localhost, see what the result is.

Comment: i dont underestand what you want, you said you want to print them seperately

Comment: [Link](https://3v4l.org/KldAN#output)
Can you check this what you said.

```<a href="CATEGORY_URL">CATEGORY_NAME</a>```

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = array(
   "category_url" => explode(',', $row['category_url']),
   "category_name" => explode(',', $row['category_name']));

   $totalEntries = count($data["category_url"]);

    for($i=0; $i < $totalEntries; $i++){
      echo '<a href="'. $data['category_url'][$i].'">';
      echo $data['category_name'][$i];
      echo '</a>';
   }
```

May this will help you..